# Am I correct in understanding the density of a uniform distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The random variable X is uniformly distributed over the interval $[10,20]$. Find $P\left\{ X\in \left[ 12,14 \right] \right\}$
I used formula :
$$P\left\{ X\in \left[ 12,14 \right] \right\} = \int_{12}^{14} p(x)dx$$
$p(x)={dx}/{14-12}$
and must be inserted into this integral (density of uniform distribution). Are my judgments correct?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The density is $p(x) = \frac{1}{20-10} = \frac{1}{10}$ for $10<x<20$, and zero elsewhere.

Comment: @GEdgar what value to substitute in the formula

Answer (score 1):

The desired probability is simply the ratio of the length of the interval of integration (which is 2) to the total length where the density is non-zero (which is 10), thus $0.2.$

p(x) is not dx/(14-12), it is just 1/10. More specifically, p(x) = 1/10 when $x\in[10,20]$ and $0$ when $x\notin[10,20]$. Using this p(x) I recommend you manually verify the first paragraph of what I wrote if it's not clear why.

Comment: No, $p(x) = 1/(20 -10) = 0.1$ for $x \in [10, 20]$.

Comment: Sorry, but your answer is nonsense.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Thanks I fixed it

Comment: @callculus42 why?

Comment: @Alborz It seems that you've found out by yourself.

Comment: @callculus42 i made a small mistake in the formula of the density. i wouldn't exactly call that nonsense..

Comment: .I didn't want my comment  sounds  offensive  Sorry, if it was so. My main problem was that you've fixed the flaw after hours and not immediately.

Comment: @callculus42 No problem, and apologies for that but I've got to sleep some time :)